# Overlapping range integration

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

Given that you only have whats above the red arrow how would you go about to get the answer. I am struggling to see how this works when there is a overlapping range.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since$$\int_{0}^{2}3f(x)dx=\int_{\color{red}{0}}^{\color{red}{1}}3f(x)dx+\int_{\color{blue}{1}}^{\color{blue}{2}}3f(x)dx$$
$$\int_{1}^{3}3f(x)dx=\int_{\color{blue}{1}}^{\color{blue}{2}}3f(x)dx+\int_{\color{green}{2}}^{\color{green}{3}}3f(x)dx$$
$$\int_{0}^{3}2f(x)dx=\int_{\color{red}{0}}^{\color{red}{1}}2f(x)dx+\int_{\color{blue}{1}}^{\color{blue}{2}}2f(x)dx+\int_{\color{green}{2}}^{\color{green}{3}}2f(x)dx$$
we have
$$\left(\int_{\color{red}{0}}^{\color{red}{1}}3f(x)dx+\int_{\color{blue}{1}}^{\color{blue}{2}}3f(x)dx\right)+\left(\int_{\color{blue}{1}}^{\color{blue}{2}}3f(x)dx+\int_{\color{green}{2}}^{\color{green}{3}}3f(x)dx\right)$$$$-\left(\int_{\color{red}{0}}^{\color{red}{1}}2f(x)dx+\int_{\color{blue}{1}}^{\color{blue}{2}}2f(x)dx+\int_{\color{green}{2}}^{\color{green}{3}}2f(x)dx\right)-\int_{\color{blue}{1}}^{\color{blue}{2}}3f(x)dx$$
$$=\int_{\color{red}{0}}^{\color{red}{1}}3f(x)dx-\int_{\color{red}{0}}^{\color{red}{1}}2f(x)dx$$$$+\int_{\color{blue}{1}}^{\color{blue}{2}}3f(x)dx+\int_{\color{blue}{1}}^{\color{blue}{2}}3f(x)dx-\int_{\color{blue}{1}}^{\color{blue}{2}}2f(x)dx-\int_{\color{blue}{1}}^{\color{blue}{2}}3f(x)dx$$
$$+\int_{\color{green}{2}}^{\color{green}{3}}3f(x)dx-\int_{\color{green}{2}}^{\color{green}{3}}2f(x)dx$$

Comment: I am not seeing it, could you expand upon your answer?

Comment: @ALEXANDER: I added a bit. Then, can you see that we can get the expression right after the red arrow?